# Starting with 200% xplodium bonus in Gun Bros

Tags: ios, gun-bros

So last week I was surprised to see that I was starting out levels with a 200% xplodium bonus, and after each wave the bonus would increase by 10%, and maxed out at 400%.  This differs from the usual 100% start, 5% increase, and 200% max.

Today, I was disappointed to see that I started out at 100% again.  I googled it and someone mentioned that it was a St. Patrick's Day easter egg of sorts, but this clearly doesn't apply to what I saw, since it was obviously not St. Patty's Day when I experienced this.

Can anyone explain this?  Is there a way to unlock this "feature" again?

Comment: It's doing it again!!  I'm at the 400% multiplier for some reason.

Comment: It's weird -- it actually goes between 200% and 400% during my game.  When I got to Wave 50 for Revolution 10, I basically continuously paused & resumed, or hit the home button and switched back to the game, just so I could end the revolution with a 400% multiplier.